# Location-code is not working anymore

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager, android-gps

I am using this code in android 6.0 to get the position:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener{
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected LocationListener locationListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (checkPermission())
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        lati = location.getLatitude();
        longi = location.getLongitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("Latitude", "disable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("Latitude", "enable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.d("Latitude", "status");
    }

    private boolean checkPermission(){
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I set the permissions in the programs properties to true.

It used to work but now it never finds satellites or the position in general.

Google maps immediately finds satellites.

What do I need to change?

Comment: Whats happend? Error? what point see? ??

Comment: Nothing. The location icon showed up and it seemed as if it was searching for a position yet never finding one. Then I opened Maps and there it was, the location, immediately. So it is not a hardware problem.

Comment: @P.Dee Try to change `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 22 and then if its working fine then its permission issue. You have to ask for location permission in `Marshmallow+` devices.

Answer (score 0):

see all that TODO comment in your code? implement it.  you *must* do this for it to work on modern versions of andorid

Comment: Even though it's no solution, I used the lastfoundlocation property in my app.